# with cte as (select id,rn2=Row_number() over(partition by id order by id) from dbo.ab1 ) delete from dbo.ab1 where rn2>1;

Tags: duplicates

The above query is throwing an Invalid column name 'rn2'. Error in SQL server. Anyone could u please help me with this. I need to remove entire duplicate record from a table that doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: What database management system do you use?

Comment: sql server database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select id,rn2=Row_number() over(partition by id order by id) 
    from dbo.ab1 
) delete from cte where rn2>1;
```

this is working. Just change the table name with cte in the delete statement.